# Can I install phpmyadmin in D: drive of my server?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I had phpmyadmin installed on my server in C:\inetpub\wwwroot and it was working. I decided to change the location of it to d:\ drive because of security problem. 
If I wanted to make the phpmyadmin login secure, it should be called in a secure page with "httpS". So I did remove the phpmyadmin folder to my D drive that has ssl. I added this line to force the ssl in config.inc "$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;"

Since that, I can see index page when I go to https://mydomain.com/pma/phpmyadmin/index.php  but will get this error when I try to login :#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
Does anybody know if it is possible to change the location for phpmyadmin? if yes, what setting do I need to make it work? If no, is there a way to make this secure in c: drive?
Thanks in advance,
Mandana

Answer (score 1):

That is not an issue with "installing" phpMyAdmin. You cannot install phpMyAdmin; it is simply a web application. What you need to do is to fix the configuration settings so that they match your MySQL user settings, either by pointing your web browser to `/path/to/phpmyadmin/install/` or editing `/path/to/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

Comment: THis is what I have in my setting: $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'q2G2rRQ0i7n4zZnSe5lSkw=='; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; /* Server parameters */ $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; /* Select mysqli if your server has it */ $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] =False; $cfg['UploadDir'] = ''; $cfg['SaveDir'] = ''; $cfg['ForceSSL'] = true; Is there anything I need to change here

Comment: Are you sure that you've set your password to the `root` account correctly?

Comment: I rest mypassword to mysql and it works now. I think I had a wrong password. Thanks.